# android change button icon when clicked

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-button

I want to know if there is a way of changing a button image when it is clicked. 
Initially the button has a pause icon. When it is clicked I want the play icon to be displayed. Each time the button is clicked the icon should vary between play and pause.

Is there any way of doing this?

XML Layout file:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
    android:src="@drawable/play_btn"
    android:background="@null" />
```

play_btn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Button mPlayButton;

boolean isPlay = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    mPlayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    // Default button, if need set it in xml via background="@drawable/default"
    mPlayButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default);
    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(mTogglePlayButton);
}

View.OnClickListener mTogglePlayButton = new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // change your button background

        if(isPlay){ 
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default);
        }else{
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playing);
        }

        isPlay = !isPlay; // reverse
    }

};
```

Comment: this works really well, but only when I click the button, then it changes back and forth with each click. however, there is no button at all before that point (only a "button shell" in the xml). do you know how to make a button appear (with the first icon you want to use) and then have this toggling take over from there? having a hard time with that part. i try adding a visible button, but the when i click it, the toggle does not work, it only stays on that original set button.

Comment: Installing your own listener is overkill and changing the background resource mutilates other properties (such as press colour and shape) of the button

Answer (score 15):

[Android's Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) with a custom selector sounds like what you want.

You might use something like this for your button's selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_icon" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause_icon" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Is this the only thing you need? so if your button is clicked, it will switch to the other drawable, and if it is clicked again, it will switch back to your first drawable?

Answer (score 7):

Let's add an `onClick` field to your button's xml in your layout (requires API level 4 and onwards)

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    ...
    android:onClick="buttonPressed" />
```

Your icons are drawables `pause` and `play`.

Keep track of which icon your button has.

```
private boolean paused = true;

public void buttonPressed(View view) {

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view;
    int icon;

    if (paused) {
        paused = false;
        icon = R.drawable.pause;
    else {
        paused = true;
        icon = R.drawable.play;
    }

    button.setImageDrawable(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), icon));


}
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because it allows you to change only the icon of the ImageButton without changing the background shape underneath it (if you are using one).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html specifically the inherited methods from android.widget.imageview.  You'll want to use either setImageBitmap or setImageDrawable.  Update it as part of your on click code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaterialButton instead of Button and then just use setIcon method for your button:

```
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;

MaterialButton mPlayButton;

boolean isPlay = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    mPlayButton = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
}

View.OnClickListener mTogglePlayButton = new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // change your button background

        if(isPlay){ 
            v.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable_resource));
        }else{
            v.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable_resource2));
        }

        isPlay = !isPlay; // reverse
    }

};
```